# get method of cls-hooked returns undifined

Tags: node.js, cls-hooked

I have question.
I am testing cls-hooked library and, I saw cls-hooked examples so, I used cls-hooked library like that cls-hooked examples.
but, cls-hooked get() method returns undefined When I use ns.get() and, It was only undefined, after ns.run().
I reference my testing github url.
[github](https://github.com/ppabew/2022-zerocho-node-lecture-study/blob/master/lecture/HttpTest.js)

Why can I get values only inside ns.run() method?
please answer to me.

```
const http = require('http');
const createNamespace = require('cls-hooked').createNamespace
const getNamespace = require('cls-hooked').getNamespace

const sessionName = 'cats'

const namespace = createNamespace(sessionName)
console.log('namespace', namespace)

function someDeepNestedCallToSet() {
    namespace.run(() => {
        namespace.set('a', 'value');

        console.log(1,namespace);
        console.log(2,namespace.get('a'));
    })
    console.log(3,namespace.get('a'));
    console.log(4,namespace);
}

function someDeepNestedCallToGet() {
    const session = getNamespace(sessionName);
    const baseObject = session.get('a')

    console.log('is working: ', baseObject);
}

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    someDeepNestedCallToSet();
    someDeepNestedCallToGet()
    console.log('서버 실행');
}).listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('8081번 포트에서 서버 대기중입니다.')
});
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le0qA.png)
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkaMG.png)